# R Studio crashing on Mac OS X 10.11.6

Tags: mysql, r, macos, rstudio

I wonder if someone can help guide me on how I can preempt a crash of R studio.  R Studio has now crashed on three separate occasions, each time 9 minutes after running the following code in an attempt to transform a dummy-variabled data set into a dataframe:

```
trsf <- events.data.frame(predict(dmy, newdata = events))
```

In the middle of running the code, RStudio "quits unexpectedly" and I get the bomb dialog box that says "R session aborted.  R encountered a fatal error. The session was terminated," and then gives me the option of starting a new session. The code that was successfully executed before running that command was:

```
dmy <- dummyVars(" ~ .", data = events)
```

Before the above command I established a connection between R Studio to my MySQL database, and then successfully read in a table from that database into R studio.

I followed the instructions at the following link to try and recover a crash report, but I couldn't find it in the locations specified:

https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200554776-RStudio-Crash-Report

The following entry showed up in the Console right when R Studio crashed:

7/30/17 11:25:53.000 AM kernel[0]: low swap: killing pid 476 (rsession)

I tried updating R studio to version 1.1.319, restarted the computer, and tried again from scratch with an empty session, but to no avail, as I continue to get the fatal error message at the same point in the process.  I then tried to reduce the size of the dataset queried of the table (5.8 GiB table with 7,201,341 rows large) by at least half by querying data (from 1997-2016, instead of data from 1974-2016).

I ran the following command in a terminal:
/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/RStudio --run-diagnostics

as mentioned here:
https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/212693307-RStudio-crash-every-time-upon-new-Rmd-file-creation

Here is the output from the text file that was created, although I'm not sure how relevant it is:

```
[1] "1.1.319"

  $R
  [1] "/usr/local/bin/R"

  $pdflatex
  [1] ""

  $bibtex
  [1] ""

$gcc
[1] "/usr/bin/gcc"

$git
[1] "/usr/bin/git"

$svn
[1] "/usr/bin/svn"

R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X El Capitan 10.11.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.0 tools_3.4.0   

SysInfo:
                                                                                          sysname 
                                                                                         "Darwin" 
                                                                                          release 
                                                                                         "15.6.0" 
                                                                                          version 
"Darwin Kernel Version 15.6.0: Sun Jun  4 21:43:07 PDT 2017; root:xnu-3248.70.3~1/RELEASE_X86_64" 
                                                                                         nodename 
                                                                                  “xxxx-Mac-Pro" 
                                                                                          machine 
                                                                                         "x86_64" 
                                                                                            login 
                                                                                     "xxxx" 
                                                                                             user 
                                                                                     "xxxx" 
                                                                                   effective_user 
                                                                                     "xxxx" 

R Version:
               _                           
platform       x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0   
arch           x86_64                      
os             darwin15.6.0                
system         x86_64, darwin15.6.0        
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          4.0                         
year           2017                        
month          04                          
day            21                          
svn rev        72570                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
nickname       You Stupid Darkness         
$`_`
[1] "/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/RStudio"

$`__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING`
[1] "0x1F5:0x0:0x0"

$Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render
[1] "/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.R8X6ErkBu8/Render"

$CLICOLOR_FORCE
[1] "1"

$DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH
[1] "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib:/Users/xxxx/lib:/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib:::/lib:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/server"

$EDITOR
[1] "vi"

$GIT_ASKPASS
[1] "rpostback-askpass"

$HOME
[1] "/Users/xxxx"

$LANG
[1] "en_US.UTF-8"

$LC_CTYPE
[1] "en_US.UTF-8"

$LN_S
[1] "ln -s"

$LOGNAME
[1] “xxxx”

$MAKE
[1] "make"

$OLDPWD
[1] "/Users/xxxx”

$PAGER
[1] "/usr/bin/less"

$PATH
[1] "/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin"

$PWD
[1] "/Users/xxxx”

$R_BROWSER
[1] "/usr/bin/open"

$R_BZIPCMD
[1] "/usr/bin/bzip2"

$R_DOC_DIR
[1] "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/doc"

$R_GZIPCMD
[1] "/usr/bin/gzip"

$R_HOME
[1] "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources"

$R_INCLUDE_DIR
[1] "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include"

$R_LIBS_SITE
[1] ""

$R_LIBS_USER
[1] "~/Library/R/3.4/library"

$R_PAPERSIZE
[1] "a4"

$R_PDFVIEWER
[1] "/usr/bin/open"

$R_PLATFORM
[1] "x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0"

$R_PRINTCMD
[1] "lpr"

$R_QPDF
[1] "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/qpdf"

$R_RD4PDF
[1] "times,inconsolata,hyper"

$R_SESSION_TMPDIR
[1] "/var/folders/ml/3khdh0ns3410w6qzm2tw6psc0000gn/T//RtmpCpoqW2"

$R_SHARE_DIR
[1] "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/share"

$R_SYSTEM_ABI
[1] "osx,gcc,gxx,gfortran,?"

$R_TEXI2DVICMD
[1] "/usr/local/bin/texi2dvi"

$R_UNZIPCMD
[1] "/usr/bin/unzip"

$R_ZIPCMD
[1] "/usr/bin/zip"

$RMARKDOWN_MATHJAX_PATH
[1] "/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/Resources/resources/mathjax-26"

$RS_RPOSTBACK_PATH
[1] "/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/rpostback"

$RS_SHARED_SECRET
[1] "5ff181b1-d899-4d78-9493-06b24535ea1b"

$RSTUDIO
[1] "1"

$RSTUDIO_CONSOLE_COLOR
[1] "256"

$RSTUDIO_CONSOLE_WIDTH
[1] "80"

$RSTUDIO_PANDOC
[1] "/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/pandoc"

$RSTUDIO_SESSION_PORT
[1] "40358"

$RSTUDIO_USER_IDENTITY
[1] "xxxx"

$RSTUDIO_WINUTILS
[1] "bin/winutils"

$SED
[1] "/usr/bin/sed"

$SHELL
[1] "/bin/bash"

$SHLVL
[1] "1"

$SSH_AUTH_SOCK
[1] "/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.JwE0qrvHVe/Listeners"

$TAR
[1] "/usr/bin/tar"

$TERM
[1] "xterm-256color"

$TERM_PROGRAM
[1] "Apple_Terminal"

$TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION
[1] "361.1"

$TERM_SESSION_ID
[1] "F96A6E56-2585-4164-B6BC-470CE6D70216"

$TMPDIR
[1] "/var/folders/ml/3khdh0ns3410w6qzm2tw6psc0000gn/T/"

$USER
[1] “xxxx”

$XPC_FLAGS
[1] "0x0"

$XPC_SERVICE_NAME
[1] "0"

 [1] ".GlobalEnv"        "tools:rstudio"     "package:stats"    
 [4] "package:graphics"  "package:grDevices" "package:utils"    
 [7] "package:datasets"  "package:methods"   "Autoloads"        
[10] "package:base"     
Log file: rdesktop.log
--------------------------------------------------

(Empty)

Log file: rsession-xxxx.log
--------------------------------------------------

16 Jun 2017 04:17:01 [rsession-xxxx] WARNING Abort requested; LOGGED FROM: bool rstudio::session::connection::checkForAbort(boost::shared_ptr<HttpConnection>, const boost::function<void ()>) /Users/rstudio/rstudio/src/cpp/session/http/SessionHttpConnectionUtils.cpp:136
16 Jun 2017 04:51:54 [rsession-xxxx] WARNING Abort requested; LOGGED FROM: bool rstudio::session::connection::checkForAbort(boost::shared_ptr<HttpConnection>, const boost::function<void ()>) /Users/rstudio/rstudio/src/cpp/session/http/SessionHttpConnectionUtils.cpp:136
16 Jun 2017 05:07:20 [rsession-xxxx] WARNING Abort requested; LOGGED FROM: bool rstudio::session::connection::checkForAbort(boost::shared_ptr<HttpConnection>, const boost::function<void ()>) /Users/rstudio/rstudio/src/cpp/session/http/SessionHttpConnectionUtils.cpp:136
17 Jun 2017 04:12:50 [rsession-xxxx] WARNING Abort requested; LOGGED FROM: bool rstudio::session::connection::checkForAbort(boost::shared_ptr<HttpConnection>, const boost::function<void ()>) /Users/rstudio/rstudio/src/cpp/session/http/SessionHttpConnectionUtils.cpp:136
17 Jun 2017 15:35:17 [rsession-xxxx] CLIENT EXCEPTION (rsession-xxxx): (TypeError) : undefined is not an object (evaluating 'a.n.applicable');|||org/rstudio/studio/client/workbench/views/packages/PackagesPane.java#102::setPackageState|||org/rstudio/studio/client/workbench/views/packages/Packages.java#724::setViewPackageList|||org/rstudio/studio/client/workbench/views/packages/Packages.java#700::onPackageFilterChanged|||org/rstudio/studio/client/workbench/views/packages/PackagesPane.java#277::onValueChange|||com/google/gwt/event/logical/shared/ValueChangeEvent.java#127::dispatch|||com/google/web/bindery/event/shared/SimpleEventBus.java#173::doFire|||com/google/gwt/event/shared/HandlerManager.java#117::fireEvent|||com/google/gwt/event/shared/HandlerManager.java#117::fireEvent|||com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Widget.java#127::fireEvent|||com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Widget.java#127::fireEvent|||com/google/gwt/event/logical/shared/ValueChangeEvent.java#40::fire|||org/rstudio/core/client/widget/SearchWidget.java#163::onKeyUp|||com/google/gwt/event/dom/client/KeyUpEvent.java#55::dispatch|||com/google/web/bindery/event/shared/SimpleEventBus.java#173::doFire|||com/google/gwt/event/shared/HandlerManager.java#117::fireEvent|||com/google/gwt/event/shared/HandlerManager.java#117::fireEvent|||com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Widget.java#127::fireEvent|||com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Widget.java#127::fireEvent|||com/google/gwt/event/dom/client/DomEvent.java#110::fireNativeEvent|||com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Widget.java#163::onBrowserEvent|||com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Composite.java#78::onBrowserEvent|||com/google/gwt/user/client/DOM.java#1414::dispatchEvent|||com/google/gwt/user/client/impl/DOMImplStandard.java#312::dispatchEvent|||com/google/gwt/core/client/impl/Impl.java#244::apply|||com/google/gwt/core/client/impl/Impl.java#283::entry0|||http://127.0.0.1:9408/#-1::anonymous|||Client-ID: 33e600bb-c1b1-46bf-b562-ab5cba070b0e|||User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh  Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/603.2.5 (KHTML, like Gecko)
17 Jun 2017 15:35:17 [rsession-xxxx] CLIENT EXCEPTION (rsession-xxxx): (TypeError) : undefined is not an object (evaluating 'a.n.applicable');|||org/rstudio/studio/client/workbench/views/packages/PackagesPane.java#102::setPackageState|||org/rstudio/studio/client/workbench/views/packages/Packages.java#724::setViewPackageList|||org/rstudio/studio/client/workbench/views/packages/Packages.java#700::onPackageFilterChanged|||org/rstudio/studio/client/workbench/views/packages/PackagesPane.java#277::onValueChange|||com/google/gwt/event/logical/shared/ValueChangeEvent.java#127::dispatch|||com/google/web/bindery/event/shared/SimpleEventBus.java#173::doFire|||com/google/gwt/event/shared/HandlerManager.java#117::fireEvent|||com/google/gwt/event/shared/HandlerManager.java#117::fireEvent|||com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Widget.java#127::fireEvent|||com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Widget.java#127::fireEvent|||com/google/gwt/event/logical/shared/ValueChangeEvent.java#40::fire|||org/rstudio/core/client/widget/SearchWidget.java#163::onKeyUp|||com/google/gwt/event/dom/client/KeyUpEvent.java#55::dispatch|||com/google/web/bindery/event/shared/SimpleEventBus.java#173::doFire|||com/google/gwt/event/shared/HandlerManager.java#117::fireEvent|||com/google/gwt/event/shared/HandlerManager.java#117::fireEvent|||com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Widget.java#127::fireEvent|||com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Widget.java#127::fireEvent|||com/google/gwt/event/dom/client/DomEvent.java#110::fireNativeEvent|||com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Widget.java#163::onBrowserEvent|||com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Composite.java#78::onBrowserEvent|||com/google/gwt/user/client/DOM.java#1414::dispatchEvent|||com/google/gwt/user/client/impl/DOMImplStandard.java#312::dispatchEvent|||com/google/gwt/core/client/impl/Impl.java#244::apply|||com/google/gwt/core/client/impl/Impl.java#283::entry0|||http://127.0.0.1:9408/#-1::anonymous|||Client-ID: 33e600bb-c1b1-46bf-b562-ab5cba070b0e|||User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh  Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/603.2.5 (KHTML, like Gecko)
17 Jun 2017 15:35:17 [rsession-xxxx] CLIENT EXCEPTION (rsession-xxxx): (TypeError) : undefined is not an object (evaluating 'a.n.applicable');|||org/rstudio/studio/client/workbench/views/packages/PackagesPane.java#102::setPackageState|||org/rstudio/studio/client/workbench/views/packages/Packages.java#724::setViewPackageList|||org/rstudio/studio/client/workbench/views/packages/Packages.java#700::onPackageFilterChanged|||org/rstudio/studio/client/workbench/views/packages/PackagesPane.java#277::onValueChange|||com/google/gwt/event/logical/shared/ValueChangeEvent.java#127::dispatch|||com/google/web/bindery/event/shared/SimpleEventBus.java#173::doFire|||com/google/gwt/event/shared/HandlerManager.java#117::fireEvent|||com/google/gwt/event/shared/HandlerManager.java#117::fireEvent|||com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Widget.java#127::fireEvent|||com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Widget.java#127::fireEvent|||com/google/gwt/event/logical/shared/ValueChangeEvent.java#40::fire|||org/rstudio/core/client/widget/SearchWidget.java#163::onKeyUp|||com/google/gwt/event/dom/client/KeyUpEvent.java#55::dispatch|||com/google/web/bindery/event/shared/SimpleEventBus.java#173::doFire|||com/google/gwt/event/shared/HandlerManager.java#117::fireEvent|||com/google/gwt/event/shared/HandlerManager.java#117::fireEvent|||com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Widget.java#127::fireEvent|||com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Widget.java#127::fireEvent|||com/google/gwt/event/dom/client/DomEvent.java#110::fireNativeEvent|||com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Widget.java#163::onBrowserEvent|||com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Composite.java#78::onBrowserEvent|||com/google/gwt/user/client/DOM.java#1414::dispatchEvent|||com/google/gwt/user/client/impl/DOMImplStandard.java#312::dispatchEvent|||com/google/gwt/core/client/impl/Impl.java#244::apply|||com/google/gwt/core/client/impl/Impl.java#283::entry0|||http://127.0.0.1:9408/#-1::anonymous|||Client-ID: 33e600bb-c1b1-46bf-b562-ab5cba070b0e|||User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh  Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/603.2.5 (KHTML, like Gecko)
18 Jun 2017 05:26:11 [rsession-xxxxxxxx] WARNING Abort requested; LOGGED FROM: bool rstudio::session::connection::checkForAbort(boost::shared_ptr<HttpConnection>, const boost::function<void ()>) /Users/rstudio/rstudio/src/cpp/session/http/SessionHttpConnectionUtils.cpp:136
20 Jun 2017 06:29:23 [rsession-xxxx] WARNING Abort requested; LOGGED FROM: bool rstudio::session::connection::checkForAbort(boost::shared_ptr<HttpConnection>, const boost::function<void ()>) /Users/rstudio/rstudio/src/cpp/session/http/SessionHttpConnectionUtils.cpp:136
21 Jun 2017 03:31:28 [rsession-xxxx] WARNING Abort requested; LOGGED FROM: bool rstudio::session::connection::checkForAbort(boost::shared_ptr<HttpConnection>, const boost::function<void ()>) /Users/rstudio/rstudio/src/cpp/session/http/SessionHttpConnectionUtils.cpp:136
```

Please let me know what other information I can provide and where I might find it so that I can address the problem.

Here is a screenshot of the R environment before the crash took place.
[image]

Thank you in advance

Comment: How large is this MySQL table?  R runs completely in memory; if you tried to import too much MySQL data, it could crash.

Comment: Hi Tim,  the table 5.8 GiB large.  So, after the error, I tried instead to import about half of the data from the table.  After importing this half, I see that it has 7589598 observations of 169 variables.  I added a screenshot to the original post of what files were in the working environment while the code was trying to transform the data into a dataframe before R studio crashed.  Is there another way I can dummy the variables from this table without using so much memory?

Comment: Yes, work with a subsample of the original table.